# How to enter a Date into a table in TSQL? (Error converting data type varchar to datetime)

Tags: sql, t-sql, syntax

I want to enter 30/10/1988 as the date to a DOB column in a table using a procedure

```
alter procedure addCustomer 
@userName varchar(50),
@userNIC varchar(50), 
@userPassword varchar(100), 
@userDOB datetime, 
@userTypeID int, 
@userEmail varchar(50), 
@userTelephone int, 
@userAddress char(100),
@userCityID int,
@status int output
as

    declare @userID int
    declare @eid int
    declare @tid int
    declare @aid int

    execute getLastRaw 'userID','tblUserParent', @userID output

    insert into tblUserParent values (@userID, @userName, @userNIC, @userPassword, @userDOB, @userTypeID)

    execute getLastRaw 'addressID','tblAddress', @aid output

    insert into tblAddress values (@aid, @userAddress, @userID, @userCityID)

    execute getLastRaw 'emailID','tblEmail', @eid output

    insert into tblEmail values (@eid, @userEmail, @userID)

    execute getLastRaw 'telephoneID','tblTelephoneNO', @tid output

    insert into tblTelephoneNO values (@tid, @userTelephone , @userID)
    insert into tblUserCustomer values (@userID, @eid , @tid, @aid)
```

...but it gives an error when i enter like this '30/10/1988'

**Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure addCustomer, Line 0 Error converting data type varchar to datetime.**

...but when I enter like only the 30/10/1988
Incorrect syntax near '/'

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works in both SQL Server and MySql without ambiguity: `yyyy-mm-dd`, like so:

```
INSERT INTO TableName(DateColumn) VALUES ('1988-10-30');
```

...as an added benefit there's no question of whether it's a US or European style date on days like the fourth of March...

Comment: Sorry, `'1988-10-30'` is ambiguous, at least in general.  If the days of 30 had been <=12, and it was running on a French locale, then this would have been interpreted as `yyyy-*DD*-*MM*`, NOT `yyyy-mm-dd`.  For it to be unambiguous in SQL Server (and locale independent) drop the `-`s completely.

Answer (score 4):

If you would truly like to avoid the possibility of ambiguous dates based, then you should always enter it in one of the two [unambiguous date formats](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2009/12/08/unambiguous-date-formats-t-sql-tuesday-001.aspx) Answer has already been selected and it's valid but I'm a believer in spreading the knowledge ;)

As noticed by @cloud and my post representing a younger, and less wise me with a link only answer, I'll pop the contents of the [archive](https://archive.vn/ORRTf) of Jamie Thompson's answer for unambiguous date formats in TSQL

### tl;dr;

- yyyy-MM-ddTHH24:mi:ss
- yyyyMMdd HH24:mi:ss

> One of the most commonly used data types in SQL Server is [datetime]
>   which unfortunately has some vagaries around how values get casted. A
>   typical method for defining a [datetime] literal is to write it as a
>   character string and then cast it appropriately. The cast syntax looks
>   something like this: DECLARE @dt NVARCHAR(19) = '2009-12-08 18:00:00';
>
> SELECT CAST(@dt AS datetime);
>
> Unfortunately in SQL Server 2005 the result of the cast operation may
>   be dependent on your current language setting. You can discover your
>   current language setting by executing: SELECT @@LANGUAGE To
>   demonstrate how your language setting can influence the results of a
>   cast take a look at the following code: ALTER  DATABASE tempdb
>
> SET        COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90 ; --Behave like SQL Server 2005
>
> USE tempdb
>
> GO
>
> DECLARE @t TABLE (
>
> ```
>   dateString  NVARCHAR(19)
> ```
>
> );
>
> INSERT @t (dateString)
>
> VALUES ('2009-12-08 18:00:00') --'yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss'
>
> ,      ('2009-12-08T18:00:00') --'yyyy-MM-ddThh24:mi:ss'
>
> ,      ('20091208 18:00:00')   --'yyyyMMdd hh24:mi:ss'
>
> SET        LANGUAGE french;
>
> SELECT 'french' AS lang
>
> ,      DATENAME(MONTH,q.[dt]) AS mnth
>
> ,      q.[dt]
>
> FROM   (
>
> ```
>    SELECT  CAST(dateString AS DATETIME) AS dt
>
>    FROM    @t
>
>    )q;
> ```
>
> SET        LANGUAGE us_english;
>
> SELECT 'us_english' AS lang
>
> ,      DATENAME(MONTH,q.[dt]) AS mnth
>
> ,      q.[dt]
>
> FROM   (
>
> ```
>    SELECT  CAST(dateString AS DATETIME) AS dt
>
>    FROM    @t
>
>    )q; We are taking the value which can be described in words as “6pm on 8th December 2009”, defining it in three different ways, then
> ```
>
> seeing how the @@LANGUAGE setting can affect the results. Here are
>   those results: french language datetime Notice how the interpretation
>   of the month can change depending on @@LANGUAGE. If
>   @@LANGUAGE=’french’ then the string '2009-12-08 18:00:00' is
>   interpreted as 12th August 2009 (‘août’ is French for August for those
>   that don’t know) whereas if @@LANGUAGE=’us_english’ it is interpreted
>   as 8th December 2009. Clearly this is a problem because the results of
>   our queries have a dependency on a server-level or connection-level
>   setting and that is NOT a good thing. Hence I recommend that you only
>   define [datetime] literals in one of the two unambiguous date formats:
>   yyyy-MM-ddTHH24:mi:ss yyyyMMdd HH24:mi:ss That was going to be the end
>   of this blog post but then I found out that this behaviour changed
>   slightly in SQL Server 2008. Take the following code (see if you can
>   figure out what the results will be before I tell you): ALTER 
>   DATABASE tempdb
>
> SET        COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100 ; --Behave like SQL Server 2008
>
> GO
>
> USE tempdb
>
> GO
>
> SET        LANGUAGE french;
>
> DECLARE    @dt NCHAR(10) = '2009-12-08 18:00:00'; --Ambiguous date
>   format
>
> SELECT CAST(@dt AS datetime) AS [ExplicitCast]
>
> ,      DATENAME(MONTH,@dt) AS [MonthFromImplicitCast]
>
> ,      DATENAME(MONTH,CAST(@dt AS datetime)) AS
>   [MonthFromExplicitCast]; Here we are doing three different things with
>   our nchar literal: explicitly cast it as a [datetime] extract the
>   month name from the char literal using the DATENAME function (which
>   results in an under-the-covers implicit cast) extract the month name
>   from the char literal using the DATENAME function after it has been
>   explicitly casted as a [datetime] Note that the compatibility level is
>   set to SQL Server 2008 and @@LANGUAGE=’french’. Here are the results:
>   image (Were you correct?) Let’s take a look at what is happening here.
>   The behaviour when we are explicitly casting as [datetime] hasn’t
>   changed, our nchar literal is still getting interpreted as 12th August
>   rather than 8th December when @@LANGUAGE=’french’. The
>   [MonthFromExplicitCast] field is interesting though, it seems as
>   though the implicit cast has resulted in the desired value of 8th
>   December. Why is that? To get the answer we can turn to BOL’s
>   description of the DATENAME function syntax: image The implicit cast
>   is not casting to [datetime] at all, it is actually casting to [date]
>   which is a new datatype in SQL Server 2008. The new date-related
>   datatypes in SQL Server 2008 (i.e. [date], [datetime2], [time],
>   [datetimeoffset]) disregard @@LANGUAGE and hence we get behaviour that
>   is more predictable and, frankly, better. These new behaviours for SQL
>   Server 2008 were unknown to me when I began this blog post so I have
>   learnt something in the course of authoring it, I hope it has helped
>   you too. No doubt someone somewhere is going to get nastily burnt by
>   this at some point, make sure that it isn’t you by always using
>   unambiguous date formats: yyyy-MM-ddTHH24:mi:ss yyyyMMdd HH24:mi:ss
>   regardless of which version you are on!

Comment: That link is dead.

Comment: @Cloud Had to hit the archive. Pity about sqlblog.com

Comment: Haha wow, I was not expecting that! A fast response and quote from an archive of the page. Hats off to you.

Answer (score 1):

See if there is a culture setting that you can change to allow you to use dd/mm/yyyy. I believe it is expecting mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: still get the same error  Incorrect syntax near '/' when is enter it like 30/10/2011

Answer (score 0):

A potentially easy way around the problem is to use a date format with no ambiguity between `mm/dd/yyyy` and `dd/mm/yyyy` such as `dd-mmm-yyyy`, eg: `30-OCT-1988`

Comment: The parameter is a `datetime`, so the conversion is happening where you call the procedure, so have a look there. Where is the '30/10/1988' coming from? Is it directly from user input?